# What is cable reinforced rope used in playground nets called?

Tags: play-structures

This children in this photo are climbing on a rope play structure made out of cable reinforced rope. Does rope like this, that is gentle on hands,  have a specific name? I've been trying to Google it without much luck. I'm looking to buy a spool.

I'm also looking for the connectors used to join the rope together.

[image]

Comment: I googled "rope connectors" and there seems to be several types: crimped, clamped, etc. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Wire Core Rope*",  "*Cable Core Rope*", "*Wire Center Rope*", "*Combination Rope*"...

"*Combination Rope*" seems to return results for thicker "ropes", which I'd assume you'd be using for a playground. "*Combination Rope Connectors*" would be a good search term for finding the connectors.

Answer (score 2):

Wire core rope is the thing to search for. You probably want the polyester and maybe a bright and attractive color if you are doing something for kids. Good luck.